# Unable to register dll using regsvr32:The module "*.dll" failed to load

Tags: matlab, windows-7, matlab-deployment, regsvr32, dllregistration

There is a similar question from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508012/unable-to-register-dll-using-regsvr32/8401595#8401595). But I didn't find that the answer is helpful. I also used Google searched the websites, I have watched [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/the-module-msinetocx-failed-to-load/7903439e-1af2-4a05-8883-73bb0bce3bd9?tm=1323179821628) and [here](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_478.asp).
I have tried the method they told to solve this problem but not got a satisfied answer.

My operating system is 32-bit **Window 7**.  `Noncircle.dll` is generated by `Matlab` version `2010a` in another machine which installed `Matlab`. I tried to add  `Noncircle.dll` as a reference in a project written in  `C#`(I didn't install `Matlab` on my computer), but `Visual-Studio 2010` told me the error:

[image]

So I doubt that `Noncircle.dll` maybe have to be registered. So I put `Noncircle.dll` in `C:\Windows\System32` and started `Cmd.exe` as a administrator and typed:

```
regsvr32 Noncircle.dll
```

Then I got an error:

```
"The module "Noncircle.dll" failed to load.Make sure the binary is sorted at the 
 specified  path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or depenedent 
 .DLL files.The specified module coudl not be found."
```

Could you give me some hints, Thanks in advance!

**Updated on 2012/10/18**

But if I have installed `Matlab` version `2010a` on my machine, this problem is solved.

Comment: When you say that `Noncircle.dll` has been generated by MATLAB - how was it generated? Using MATLAB Compiler? Using MATLAB Builder NE for .NET? Using MATLAB Coder? Do you have the MATLAB Compiler Runtime installed on your computer (not the machine on which the .dll was generated, but your computer)?

Comment: I just click `File\New\Deployment Project`  in MATLAB to generate `Noncircle.dll`. I can't assert that in this way Matlab how to generate `Noncircle.dll`. Yes. I have the MATLAB Compiler Runtime installed on my computer, but I got the same results.

Comment: `File>New>Deployment Project` should bring up a dialog box asking for a project name and a project Type. What are you selecting for the project Type - depending on which products you have installed, you may have options including Windows Standalone Application, Console Application, C Shared Library, C++ Shared Library, .NET Assembly, Generic COM Component (and others not relevant for this question).

Comment: I selected Generic COM Component(I'm sorry for not providing the the details of generating the dll, because another guy generated the dll by MATLAB)

Comment: This happens when regsvr32.dll itself is not registered, although it is otherwise required to do this. Catch22. I am sure there are people who know how to do this, but they're not talking. Wait. This is the cause when regsvr32 says it loads the module, but it can't find the entry point.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue.

If you're running 64-bit Windows and you've placed the 32-bit DLL in Windows\System32\ then it'll give you this error.

Simply place the DLL into Windows\SysWOW64\ and register it from there.

Here's where I found the fix:

http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/73-windows-64-bit/378-fixing-qregsvr32-the-module-failed-to-load-the-specified-module-could-not-be-foundq

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to use [RegDllView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html), to see whether there is actually a COM server registered in the system.

Also check whether this DLL is a COM component.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late... but I am adding my solution for others because I faced the same error after following above mentioned answers:

"I just had the same issue.

If you're running 64-bit Windows and you've placed the 32-bit DLL in Windows\System32\ then it'll give you this error.

Simply place the DLL into Windows\SysWOW64\ and register it from there."

If you are facing same error after placing DDL to SysWOW64, then you need to turn on MSMQ feature.

Go to Start ->
Search "Turn Windows features on or off" ->
Find "Microsoft Message Queue(MSMQ) Server" and Enable it.

[image]

Now, register the same DLL again and this time it will be registered