# VB.Net ".DLL was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found"

Tags: vb.net

I am finding it difficult to discover the reason for this message. I downloaded PIA services and installed the extracted files, but when I register using `regsvr32 path\file name` I get the aforementioned message:

> .dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found

Again I tried to extract the files in systems32 folder, and the message tells me they were extracted. But when I search in the system32 folder the files aren't there. Please help me.

Comment: PIAs are not registered with Regsvr32, they require Regasm.exe.  Look in the c:\windows\syswow64 folder instead.  Don't mess with the operating system folders.

Comment: The Module "c:\windows\syswow64\o2010pia"failed to load

Comment: thanks a lot.very useful.i used syswow64.but now i m getting a message when i register windows installer.kindly help me.The Module "c:\windows\syswow64\o2010pia"failed to load.make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent dll files.the specified module could not be found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I register a .NET COM DLL with Regsvr32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198583/how-do-i-register-a-net-com-dll-with-regsvr32)

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the same issue today. It's all pretty new to me, but here's what I've found:

RegSvr32 will only work on COM libraries designed to be dynamically linkable. And as Hans Passant said: you need to use regasm instead of regsvr32 to register .NET assemblies:

```
regasm assemblyFile [options]
```

(More info on regasm can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx).)

For your second question: the DLL might link to other DLLs which aren't in the path you specified when running regasm. (As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508012/unable-to-register-dll-using-regsvr32).) Try checking all the dependencies.